# MVC4 action method logging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im building an MVC4 web application. My requirement is to log a http request's execution duration of a controller action method using log4net.

I heard that the preferred way to do this is to create a custom actionfilter - start the stopwatch in onExecuting method - then log the duration in onExecuted.

I have a custom model binder doing queries to my repositories in order to construct complex objects. Because the model binder executes before the filters, I do not ge a accurate duration reading.

I could use a custom HTTPModule, but how do I know if it routes to action method or not...

EDIT:

My action takes in a Customer domain object as parameter. I use a custom modelbinder to find the key in the url and fetch the customer object from my repo.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your model binder accessing the database is a terrible design, and you're starting to understand why.  A model binder should only bind data sent from the client.  You would be better off doing this in an ActionFilter rather than the model binder.

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit confusing. You want to track action/result execution or model binder execution. Why do you have model binder contacting your repository to construct an object? Model binder should construct an object to a type that you specify in your `HttpPost` action. As for action/result tracking here is a little reference that might help you figure out what you want to track (if you want to track using action filters).

In MVC you can track when you action started to execute and when it finished, and you can also track when the result began processing and when the result ended.

The first two options are implemented via interface `IActionFilter`. This filter requires you to implement two methods: `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted`. The first method is invoked just before the action started and the last method is invoked just after the action ended.

The second interface is concerning the result being generated. This is implemented via `IResultFilter` interface. It also contains two methods to be implemented. These are `OnResultExecuting` and `OnResultExecuted`. The first method, `OnResultExecuting` is invoked after `OnActionExecuted` completed. This is the point at which you result, let's say `ViewResult` has started processing the output that will return to a user. Once the view is ready and returned to a user, `OnResultExecuted` kicks in. This informs you that the processing is done.

Now, what you want to log is up to you. If you need to log when you action starts, makes a call to the underlying data sources and ends, then implement `IActionFilter`. If you need to track how long it takes for a result to process then implement `IResultFilter`.

You can also implement both filters at once by inheriting from `ActionFilterAttribute`.